# devtools install github ignoring certain .rda files

Tags: r, devtools

I'm currently testing out my `R` package which has two `.rda` files in the `data/` folder which can be found [here](https://github.com/sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly/tree/master/data). They were created using the `devtools::use_data` command. They are not very large files, the largest one being 713 KB. I'm trying to install my package from [GitHub](https://github.com/sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly) using `devtools`:

```
devtools::install.github('sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly')
```

But for some reason only one of the two `.rda` files gets installed (the [hapmap.rda](https://github.com/sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly/blob/master/data/hapmap.rda) file doesnt get installed):

```
 
devtools::install_github('sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly', force = TRUE, build_vignette = TRUE)
Downloading GitHub repo sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly/zipball/master
Installing manhattanly
'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD build  \
  '/tmp/RtmpEYJ9AG/devtools84183fc48b7d/sahirbhatnagar-manhattanly-0dead52' --no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpEYJ9AG/devtools84183fc48b7d/sahirbhatnagar-manhattanly-0dead52/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘manhattanly’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
* building ‘manhattanly_0.1.0.tar.gz’

'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpEYJ9AG/manhattanly_0.1.0.tar.gz'  \
  --library='/mnt/GREENWOOD_BACKUP/home/sahir.bhatnagar/Rlibs/R3.2.2' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘manhattanly’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package ‘DBI’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘jsonlite’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘manhattanly’
    finding HTML links ... done
    manhattanly                             html  

    finding level-2 HTML links ... done

    manhattanr                              html  
    qqly                                    html  
    qqr                                     html  
    significantSNP                          html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Note: the specification for S3 class “AsIs” in package ‘DBI’ seems equivalent to one from package ‘jsonlite’: not turning on duplicate class definitions for this class.
* DONE (manhattanly)
```

When I try to check the package using `devtools::check()` I also get an error when trying to build the vignette, saying that the `hapmap` object has not been found.

Any idea why this is happening? The [`.csv` file](https://github.com/sahirbhatnagar/manhattanly/blob/master/data-raw/hapmap.csv) is not that large either ~2.2 Mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .Rbuildignore file has a line:

```
hapmap.R
```

Because these are treated as regular expressions, you're telling R to ignore the hapmap.rds file, which that regex pattern also matches. Just update that with a $ or prefix the directory name to limit the regex.